# Flutter chat_gpt_sdk ERROR - Uploaded image must be a png and less than 4 mb

Tags: flutter, dart, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Can anyone help? I've been stuck on this for days... I even tried converting the path to base64 but nothing work...
by the way the file is png, less than 1MB and is a square.

These suggestion didn't help either: https://community.openai.com/t/using-image-url-in-images-edits-request/27247/3

```
void variation(File image, String name) async {
final request =
Variation(image: EditFile(image.path, name));
final response = await openAI.editor.variation(request);

print(response.data?.last?.url);
}
```

Comment: Which package is this?

Comment: @doneforaiur https://pub.dev/packages/chat_gpt_sdk - version 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

With the error

- Make sure the image file is in PNG format. Convert it to PNG if
  needed before passing it to the API.
- Verify that the file size is below 4 MB. If it exceeds the limit,
  compress or resize the image to reduce its size.
- Instead of converting to a Blob or binary, directly pass the image
  file as a parameter using the correct file path or object.

This work for me

```html
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLib;
import 'package:openai/api.dart' as openAI;

void variation(File imageFile, String name) async {
  // Verify image format and convert to PNG if necessary
  if (!imageFile.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.png')) {
    File convertedImageFile = await convertToPNG(imageFile);
    if (convertedImageFile == null) {
      print('Error: Failed to convert image to PNG format.');
      return;
    }
    imageFile = convertedImageFile;
  }

  // Verify file size and resize if necessary
  int maxSizeInBytes = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 MB
  if (imageFile.lengthSync() > maxSizeInBytes) {
    File resizedImageFile = await resizeImage(imageFile, maxSizeInBytes);
    if (resizedImageFile == null) {
      print('Error: Failed to resize image to reduce file size.');
      return;
    }
    imageFile = resizedImageFile;
  }

  // Pass the image file as a parameter in the request
  final request = openAI.Variation(
    image: openAI.EditFile(imageFile.path, name),
  );

  final response = await openAI.editor.variation(request);

  print(response.data?.last?.url);
}

// convert image file to PNG format
Future<File> convertToPNG(File imageFile) async {
  try {
    String newPath = imageFile.path.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\.\w+$'), '.png');
    imageLib.Image image = imageLib.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    File convertedImageFile = File(newPath)..writeAsBytesSync(imageLib.encodePng(image));
    return convertedImageFile;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error converting image to PNG: $e');
    return null;
  }
}

// Function to resize image file to reduce file size
Future<File> resizeImage(File imageFile, int maxSizeInBytes) async {
  try {
    double quality = 0.9; // Adjust the quality of the resized image as needed
    imageLib.Image image = imageLib.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    int currentSizeInBytes = imageFile.lengthSync();
    while (currentSizeInBytes > maxSizeInBytes) {
      image = imageLib.copyResize(image, width: (image.width * 0.9).round());
      List<int> resizedImageBytes = imageLib.encodeJpg(image, quality: quality * 100).toList();
      currentSizeInBytes = resizedImageBytes.length;
      imageFile = File(imageFile.path)..writeAsBytesSync(resizedImageBytes);
    }
    return imageFile;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error resizing image: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing thanks for the help. I did try resizing the image and making sure it was a PNG before asking for help.. Your answer is perfect but still doesn't work.
im using chat_gpt_sdk - version 2.1.2... maybe thats the problem?